# Is it possible to get two low-voltage interrupts pins on a Atmega328?

Tags: avr, atmega, interrupts

*Caution: Noob at work :)*

---

I'm trying to get one of two 1.5V-2V signal inputs to trigger an interrupt routine on an Atmega328 ([Doc PDF](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)). By using the analog comparator interrupt, I gather I block the analog-digital-converter interrupt and vice-versa.

I had a look at the ADC Auto Trigger Logic:

[image]

[image]

**I cannot understand what free running mode does. It runs continually and if it value is true, it will trigger an interrupt routine for me?**

Footnote: I could have also done this with external components, but I didn't have the parts at hand and thought I'd take it on as a learning experience in microprocessor use.

Answer (score 1):

"Free Running mode" will cause a new ADC conversion to begin once the previous one has completed. If the ADC interrupt is enabled then the ADC Conversion Complete vector will be called each time.

The Analog Comparator, on the other hand, is a completely different peripheral and is covered in an entirely different section of the datasheet.